# I want to write a prim's algorithm in java

Tags: java

actually, I want to know the meaning of the prim and Dijkstra algorithm. and I   appreciate     if someone could teach how to write it in JAVA. I try to understand someone's code of prim's algorithm, but I stuck at someplace.

The code showing below is a random matrix. and I want to proceed to write prim's algorithm. is there anybody can help?

```
 import java.util.*;
 class RandomGraph
 {
    public static Scanner br = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int w [][];
    static int n;
    static int i, j;

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Find the shortest edge");
        System.out.println("\nEnter the number of the vertices: ");
        n = br.nextInt();
        w = new int[n+1][n+1];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                if((i!=j))
                {
                w[i][j] = w[j][i]= 1+(int)(Math.random()*9);
                }
                else if(i == j)
                {
                    w[i][j] = w[j][i] = 0;
                }
            }
        Graph();
    }

    static void Graph()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                System.out.print("  "+w[i][j]+"  ");
            }
        System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/java-algorithms-implementation/source/browse/trunk/src/com/jwetherell/algorithms/graph/Prim.java?r=70

Comment: http://sourcecodesforfree.blogspot.in/2013/05/10-prims-algorithm.html

Comment: @Hariharan ehhh excuse .. can you explain a bit definition of prim's algorithm to me ?> thx

Comment: Prim's algorithm is a greedy algorithm that finds a minimum spanning tree for a connected weighted undirected graph. This means it finds a subset of the edges that forms a tree that includes every vertex, where the total weight of all the edges in the tree is minimized.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=prim%27s+algorithm+for+minimum+spanning+trees&oq=prims+algo&gs_l=youtube.3.1.0i10l5.2903.6585.0.8079.10.10.0.0.0.0.190.1206.4j6.10.0...0.0...1ac.1.11.youtube.5H9nCuXR1yc

Comment: @Hariharan how can i link this class to another class... how can i use link to realize it..

Comment: @Hariharan Link is dead. This is the current. https://code.google.com/p/java-algorithms-implementation/source/browse/src/com/jwetherell/algorithms/graph/Prim.java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **[Prims Algorithms Implementation In Java - Minimum Cost Spanning Tree](http://www.learnnowit.com/2011/02/prims-algorithms-implementation-in-java.html)**

```
public class Prim {
    int weightArray[][] = new int[20][20];
    int visited[] = new int [20];
    int d[] = new int[20];
    int p[] = new int[20];
    int verticeCount, edgeCount;
    int nodeA, nodeB, weight;
    int current, total, mincost;


    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        // Instantiate the graph based on input
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("\nEnter number of vertices: ");
        verticeCount = Integer.parseInt(buf.readLine());
        System.out.print("\nEnter number of edges: ");
        edgeCount = Integer.parseInt(buf.readLine());
        for (int i = 1; i <= verticeCount; i++) {
            for(int j = 1; j <= verticeCount; j++) {
                weightArray[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }

       for (int i = 1; i <= verticeCount; i++) {
           p[i] = visited[i] = 0;
           d[i] = 32767;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= edgeCount; i++) {
            System.out.print("\nEnter edge nodeA, nodeB and weightArray weight: ");
            nodeA=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
            nodeB=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
            weight=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
            weightArray[nodeA][nodeB] = weightArray[nodeB][nodeA] = weight;
        }
        // End of graph instantiation

        current = 1;
        d[current] = 0;
        total = 1;
        visited[current] = 1;
        while( total != verticeCount) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= verticeCount; i++) {
                if ( weightArray[current][i] != 0) {
                    if( visited[i] == 0) { 
                        if (d[i] > weightArray[current][i]) {
                            d[i] = weightArray[current][i];
                            p[i] = current;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            mincost=32767;
            for (int i = 1 ; i <= verticeCount; i++) {
                if (visited[i] == 0) {
                    if (d[i] < mincost) {
                        mincost = d[i];
                        current = i;
                    }
                }
            }
            visited[current]=1;
            total++;
        }

        mincost=0;
        for(i=1;i<=verticeCount;i++)
        mincost=mincost+d[i];

        System.out.print("\n Minimum cost="+mincost);
        System.out.print("\n Minimum Spanning tree is");

        for(i=1;i<=verticeCount;i++)
        System.out.print("\n vertex" +i+"is connected to"+p[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: furthermore, i still have some questions needed to be solved...can we chat?

Comment: @AnkurLathi, maybe you can edit "Prims Algorithms Implementation In Java MINIMUM COST SPANNING TREE" to
"Prims Algorithms Implementation In Java **minimum cost spanning tree**"

Comment: https://github.com/cs4alhaider/Prims-algorithm

Comment: I wish someone had provided a code that uses PriorityQueue for finding the next minimum edge.

Answer (score 0):

Prim's algorithm:

Prim's algorithm is a greedy algorithm that finds a minimum spanning tree for a connected weighted undirected graph. This means it finds a subset of the edges that forms a tree that includes every vertex, where the total weight of all the edges in the tree is minimized.

Definition:

- Create a tree containing a single vertex, chosen arbitrarily from the
  graph
- Create a set containing all the edges in the graph
- Loop until every edge in the set connects two vertices in the tree

  - Remove from the set an edge with minimum weight that connects a vertex in the tree with a vertex not in the tree
- Add that edge to the tree

Wiki link - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim's_algorithm

Example link:

http://github.com/phishman3579/java-algorithms-implementation/blob/master/src/com/jwetherell/algorithms/graph/Prim.java

http://sourcecodesforfree.blogspot.in/2013/05/10-prims-algorithm.html