# Is it possible to implement a PriorityQueue in Java using a comparator that compare element in an external array?

Tags: java, priority-queue, comparator

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
int[] key = new int[col.length];
PriorityQueue<Integer> heap = new PriorityQueue<>((Integer u, Integer v) -> key[u]-key[v]);
```

I have been testing it out by changing the value of key in a `while(!heap.isEmpty())` loop and it seems like it works sometimes but sometimes it won't update. I also try force update with `heap.add(heap.poll())` but it doesn't seem like it always work.

My example is implementing MST-Prim so I don't think posting it here would be helpful. Nevertheless, I hope someone could tell if it works or I'm just doing something wrong.

Comment: I think the priorities of the values in the PriorityQueue are not permitted to change their value while they are in the queue.

Comment: Did you make it work without the expression?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you guys mean.

Comment: Try to accomplish it by passing a Comparator<? extends E> (E being the generic argument) Once that is working get fancy

Comment: You absolutely can't change the ordering of elements while they're in the queue, period.  There's absolutely no way.

Comment: Then do you guys know what I should implement MST-Prim with ?

Comment: Represent the heap in an array. Binary trees are easily represented in arrays, this should allow you to change the array/heap at will

Comment: Or an array List to dynamically change sizes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to write a prim's algorithm in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18009158/i-want-to-write-a-prims-algorithm-in-java)

Comment: Note that a comparator that returns the result of `x - y` will fail when `x` is large and `y` is a negative number. For example, if `x` is the maximum integer that can be represented and `y` is -1, the result will be negative, incorrectly indicating that `x < y`.

Comment: How is this a duplicate? I'm asking why my specific implementation of a priority queue doesn't work and somehow, this is the same as how to implement Prim. The only thing that is related to Prim is one of my comment below and it is how I should implement a heap that works for Prim not how to implement Prim.